# High Availability Exchange 2010 Support on Server 2008 Standard?

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2010

I could not find an answer so I thought I'd ask here:

Is Microsoft Exchange 2010 High Availability possible on Exchange 2010 Standard running on Server 2008 R2 Standard boxes?

This is one of the features I like about Exchange 2010.  My concern is that if it can be avoided the business does not necessarily need a Enterprise server license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DAG feature is available in both editions of Exchange 2010, but only when running on Windows Enterprise or Datacenter. DAG uses Windows Failover Clustering, which is not available in the Standard edition.

Answer (score 0):

I know about two products that can provide redundancy in case where you have only Standard Windows installed and don't want to migrate to Enterprise version:

1. [DoubleTake](http://www.visionsolutions.com/products/dt-avail.aspx)
2. [Steeleye](http://us.sios.com/products/steeleye-protection-suite-windows/application-recovery-kits/)

I'm sure there are a lot more, those I worked with.